# django rest framework simple post method with two related objects

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a simple Django Rest Framework application storing a listening history, which consists of a ListeningHistory, a Track and an Artist model. Each ListeningHistory record is related to one track, and each track is related to one or multiple artists. If a track or an artist already exists, it should re-use that record and not try to create a new one.

models.py:

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)


class Track(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    artists = models.ManyToManyField(Artist)
    album = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)


class ListeningHistory(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-played_at']

    played_at = models.DateTimeField(unique=True)
    track = models.ForeignKey(Track, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

serializers.py:

```
class ArtistSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Artist
        fields = '__all__'


class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    artists = ArtistSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        artists_data = validated_data.pop('artists')
        track, created = Track.objects.get_or_create(**validated_data)
        artists = [Artist.objects.get_or_create(name=artist_data['name'])[0] for artist_data in artists_data]
        track.artists.set(artists)
        return track


class ListeningHistorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    track = TrackSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = ListeningHistory
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        track_data = validated_data.pop('track')
        artists_data = track_data.pop('artists')
        track, created = Track.objects.get_or_create(**track_data)
        artists = [Artist.objects.get_or_create(name=artist_data['name'])[0] for artist_data in artists_data]
        track.artists.set(artists)
        listening_history = ListeningHistory.objects.create(track=track, **validated_data)
        return listening_history
```

views.py:

```
class ListeningHistoryAPIView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = ListeningHistorySerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The first post works, but when I try to post another record with existing track and/or artist, the serializer validation fails. What would be the proper way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing is related to how you're handling the creation of existing tracks and artists in your serializers. To ensure that the serializer works correctly, you should update your **TrackSerializer** and **ListeningHistorySerializer** to handle existing records properly. You can use the **get** method to retrieve existing records and only create new ones if they don't already exist. Here's how you can modify your **serializers**:

In your **TrackSerializer**, modify the create method like this:

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    artists = ArtistSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        artists_data = validated_data.pop('artists')
        
        # Check if the track already exists
        track, created = Track.objects
```